# DocxJS - how to apply mirrored margins for generated document?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, docx

I am trying to generate dynamic docx document and I have to apply specific margins to pages.

I have to apply **Mirrored** margins for pages but I cannot replicate this with docxjs.

[image]

What I have tried so far:

[image]

This converts to such output:

[image]

**Inside** and **Outside** values are missing....

Any solution for this?